# Accessing blockchain.info account without email address

Tags: blockchain.info, lost-wallet

I had my **blockchain.info** Id in my email account but it got hacked. Because of that I have **disabled** the account. How can I get access to my blockchain id and **password** now?

Comment: Contact blockchain.info support. An e-mail account is not a safe place to store passwords, login names etc. Use a medium and storage place that is reasonably safe against loss/destruction and theft.